# How do you ban people from your world in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend Evan,is griefing me. When I went on his world to get revenge, he banned me. The screen said " HerobineYoung has banned enderpizza you will be kicked out in 5 minutes." I begged him to tell me how but he wouldn't tell me.

How can I ban people in Minecraft PE?

Answer (score 2):

Your 'friend' was able to ban you because he was using a separate server app to play with you, not the built-in server (which doesn't take any commands at all).

Most Minecraft PE server programs/apps support administrative commands reminiscent of those in the regular Minecraft server, such as `/kick`, `/ban`, and `/echo`.

Comment: (You don't have to answer), but which update did it come out in?

Comment: @aytimothy For PC? Admin commands have existed since Alpha, when the rather buggy dedicated SMP server was introduced. (Non-dedicated servers were added at the end of Beta.)

Comment: Of course not PC (because that would just be me being very dumb).. Pocket Edition.

Comment: @atimothy umm.. admin commands still haven't been added for vanilla PE