# How do I kick someone from my PE server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an annoying person on my Pocket Edition LAN server and I do not know how to disconnect him without closing the game/server? (As in: returning to the home screen).

Comment: Possibly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198373/how-do-you-ban-people-from-your-world-in-minecraft-pe

Answer (score 2):

Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to open the menu with wifi, bluetooth, brightness, and Do Not Disturb toggle button. Turn off the wifi, then turn it on again.

Answer (score 2):

if you have cheats on type /kick (playername) and they should be kicked from your game with the screen "You have been kicked from the game".

Answer (score -1):

Go onto settings and options then go onto private no Lan